# numpy - compare each element of two arrays and return matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, machine-learning

I have a vector of predicted probabilities.  I want to compare each probability with several thresholds and end up with a matrix result[i,j] that saves a Boolean value for if probability[i] was greater than threshold[j].

This is what I have so far...

```
y = np.random.randint(2, size=6)

pred = np.array([0.21,0.37,0.18,0.88,0.54,0.23])

thresh = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])

pred_true = []
for i in range(thresh.shape[0]): #for each threshold
    pred_true.append(pred > thresh[i])

v_pred_true = np.vstack(pred_true).T
v_pred_true
```

gives:

```
Out[40]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

But I'd like to find a more numpythonic way to do this.

Comment: `pred[:,None] > thresh`?

Comment: oh wow, that works!  i wasn't aware of using None for indexing.  thanks

Comment: This might help in understanding - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html. None is an alias for numpy.newaxis there.

Comment: Another easy way is to use the `outer` method fo `np.greater`. `np.greater.outer(pred, thresh)`. Free bonus: it handles multidimensional inputs as well.

Comment: anybody wanna post an answer and collect the points?